# Docker cloud plugin for Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, dockerfile, devops

all.
Im using docker cloud plugin in my jenkins platform.

```
https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/
```

But i wonder where can i find the workspace within this agent.
My some builds failing and putting logs file inside container. I couldnt find these files.
Do you know where to search workpace ? In docker host itself ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it on the host, which was configured to run containers in Configure Clouds menu.

[image: Docker Host URI]

But it is not configured in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the "Volumes" section ?

Comment: Manage jenkins -> Manage nodes and clouds -> Configure clouds. Add volume to 'Docker agent template'